# How get route's params with Nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, vuejs3-composition-api

I used Nuxt3 with Composition API.
When moving from bakset to order, basket is using router.push, and is turning over parameters. How can I get these parameters from order? In the nuxt2 version, you can easily get them using context.params, but I don't know how to get them in the nuxt3 version.

```
bakset.vue
navigateTo({
    name: 'or-order-Order',
    path: '/or/order/Order',
    params: {
      ordMediaCd: '01'
    }
  });


Order.vue
how to get params 'ordMediaCd'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useRoute().params` to get the route params. See [docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-route) for more about `useRoute()`.